# positive Operator in $L_2(0,1)$ and its $n^{th}$ root

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-algebras

Let $A \in \mathcal{B} (L_2(0,1))$ be defined by $Af(t)= tf(t)$. We want to show that $A \geq 0$ and find $A^{1/n}$.

What I have tried for the first part of the question is as follows.
It is known that $A \geq 0 $ if and only if $\langle f, Af \rangle  \geq 0$ for all $f \in L_2(0,1)$. Let $f \in L_2(0,1)$ and so 
\begin{align*}
\langle f , Af \rangle &= \int_0^1 f(t) \overline{Af}(t)dt \\
& = \int_0^1 t f(t) \overline{f(t)} dt = \int_0^1 t |f(t)|^2 dt
\end{align*}
which is positive. Firstly I am not sure my reasoning is correct or not, and also I have no clue the second part of the question. In fact we know that since $A \geq 0$, thus, there exist a unique positive element $T$ such that $A = T^n$. However, how should we find an explicit form for that? 
Thanks in advance for your helps.

Comment: Have you tried $Tf = t^{1/n}f$?

Comment: well I though about something like this. However, I am not sure how should I discuss that this is in fact the $n^{th}$ root of $A$.

Comment: Apply $T$ $n$ times to $f$ to see that you get $tf(t)$.

Comment: Yes you are right thank you so much

Comment: @nick ..which book it is can you tell me please

Answer (score 1):

Your proof of $A\geq 0$ is correct. More generally, multiplication with a positive bounded function is a positive operator on $L^2$ (see below).

One way to get $A^{1/n}$ is simply to show that the multiplication by $t^{1/n}$ satisfies the defining properties of $A^{1/n}$.

More conceptually, you can prove that the map $\Phi\colon C([0,1])\to \mathcal{B}(L^2((0,1))$ that maps a function $\phi$ to the multiplication operator $\Phi(\phi)f:=\phi f$ is linear and satisfies $\Phi(\phi\psi)=\Phi(\phi)\Phi(\psi)$, $\Phi(\overline\phi)=\Phi(\phi)^\ast$. It is an immediate consequence that $\Phi(|\phi|^2)=\Phi(\phi)^\ast\Phi(\phi)$, hence positive functions are mapped to positive operators.

Moreover, it follows by induction that $\Phi(\phi^n)=\Phi(\phi)^n$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$. So you're left with the task to find a positive function $\phi\in C([0,1])$ that satisfies $\phi(t)^{n}=t$, and well, there is $\phi(t)=t^{1/n}$ again.

Comment: Thank you so much for your insightful argument. In fact, I was trying to have  such an argument for an operator $T: L_2(0,1) \rightarrow L_2(0,1)$, but I couldn't construct the *-homomorphism. The key point here is how you have defined the map from $C([0,1])$. Could you please explain how should we come up with  the map from $C([0,1])$.?

Comment: From an abstract point of view, this map is the GNS construction associated with the state $\int\cdot\,dx$ on $C([0,1])$. But honestly I don't know how to come up with this idea on your own - I've just seen and used it too often.

Comment: Thank you so much any way for your helps.